# Scenario specific: Windows Services vs Azure Job, Console app in Scheduler on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, windows-services, console-application

### Scenario:

We have a web application in which every user in our site can add multiple accounts of some other social sites, like Facebook, Twitter, etc.

We have to perform some automated jobs (like get data via API's from their accounts to generate analytics for these users)

### Key Point

User can start or stop the service for any account to stop or start collecting data for analytics.
When user click on start/stop I have to start that automated windows service/crone job/console app in scheduler.

### Concerns to be cleared:

1. For user `x` who have `n` number of social accounts added, Should i start thread for each account, or thread per user, or `y` number of users per thread?
2. What would be the optimized approach for that, windows service? console App in scheduler? or some kind of database triggers that can work with windows service? or some third party library like `Quartz.Net` or `hangfire` etc?

Web application is developed in ASP.NET MVC, MSSQL Server, c# and deployed on dedicated windows server.

#### Edit

1. Keep in mind that if user start a service for one account and wont stop it for long time, We need that service to keep working.
2. We don't want immediate operations in service, we can delay user operations for one or two minuets.

Like we can read user activity on Facebook after one or two minutes rather than after every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to advise you something without any details, but for me it looks like you're talking about some kind of `push`-notification system with a huge backend-side computations. Console app and scheduler is a bad idea for me, as you'll have to start yet another process for each new user, and eventually you just blow the server up with a new tasks on it.

The same is about the threads - one of them takes your memory for a system stuff like call stack, local storage and so on. If your user base is big enough, your app will get the thread starvation instead of performance gain. You probably need to split your data processing into tasks with [`TPL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), maybe [write your own `TaskScheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx), but try to avoid long-running ones, which will poll for a the user requests continuously.

So solution could be like some event-based app (with [`RabbitMQ` queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html), for example), which spawn some number of tasks for each requests, as granulated as possible, like is user `A` wants to know the `Facebook` and `Twitter` update, start two tasks, and notify user about their completion separately, so you get as much scalability as possible.

To go cloud or not, it's up to you, probably you need some measurements here with profilers, but for me it sounds like you really need it. Internal processing may be implemented with [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) library, with a block representing one type of processing, and some kind of aggregating logic at the end.

All in all, event-based approach provide you a way to handle users request in asynchronous fashion, with some push notifications or client polling back to them. Inside the processing engine, create a big number of small tasks so your app wouldn't stuck with some greedy user reports.

Comment: Thank you @VmAtm for great suggestions.